# Shell Script - Search for a multiline pattern and delete record if there is a match

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a file in the following format.

```
I PRP B-PRP
am VBP B-VBP
a DT B-DT
happy JJ B-JJ
soul NN B-NN

I PRP B-PRP
am VBP B-VBP
a DT B-DT
sad JJ B-JJ
soul NN B-NN
```

Every record is separated by an empty line. Each line has 3 fields.

If there is an input *I am a happy soul* I wanted to search inside this file and delete the record if it is present. In this example, record one will be deleted from the file. Since the sentence is spread as multiple lines, I can't figure out how to do this. I tried **sed**, **awk**, **grep**. Nothing seems to work. Basically, I can't figure out how to give the pattern for those commands.

```
sed -e '/I/,/soul/!d' filename
```

Most of the comments are like the above type, *begin pattern* followed by *end pattern*. But this won't work in my case.

How can solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If there is an input I am a happy soul I wanted to search inside this file and delete the record if it is present.

You can use this `awk` command:

```
awk -v RS= '!/^I .*\nam .*\nhappy .*\nsoul /' file

I PRP B-PRP
am VBP B-VBP
a DT B-DT
sad JJ B-JJ
soul NN B-NN
```

Comment: how to pass the `regex` as a shell variable? Is that possible?

Comment: Yes. It's possible.

Comment: There is a problem. When it prints the result, the record separator blank line is missing. How to solve this?

Comment: `echo -e "`awk -v RS= "$pattern{print "";print "\n";}" file`"` made the trick.

Comment: or you can do `awk -v RS= '!/^I .*\nam .*\nhappy .*\nsoul /{print $0 "\n"}' file`

Answer (score 2):

Using AWK one can set `RS` (Record Seperator) to nothing, to split records on empty lines:

```
$ awk '/I.*am.*happy.*soul/' RS= input.txt
I PRP B-PRP
am VBP B-VBP
a DT B-DT
happy JJ B-JJ
soul NN B-NN
```

`.*` is two regex metacharacters, `.` means any character, while `*` means zero or more times.

I'm not sure how well defined it is that `.` matches newlines.

Comment: Wouldn't it fail for `III mam ahappyp asould`, then again I'm not sure if it matters?

Comment: @JamesBrown That is true, one can use word boundaries to avoid that. But I'm not sure about the support for each syntax, i.e: GNU awk supports `\<` and `\>`, but I don't think that POSIX awk do.

Answer (score 1):

The exact approach (except the order, that would require `a[$i]=i` and `... ("am" in a) && a["I"]<a["am"] && ...`):

```
$ awk -v RS=  '
{
    delete a; 
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)  # iterate every word
        a[$i]           # and store it
} 
("I" in a) && ("am" in a) && ("a" in a) && ("happy" in a) && ("soul" in a) {next} 1
' test
I PRP B-PRP
am VBP B-VBP
a DT B-DT
happy JJ B-JJ
soul NN B-NN
```

---

**Edit**: Version that tests for exact word matches and the order of the words in the block (well, record in this case) and accepts the searched words as a parameter (see `s` in code):

```
$ awk -v ORS="\n\n" -v RS=  -v s="I am a happy soul" '
BEGIN {
    n=split(s,a)              # split the searched sentance to a hash
}
{
    delete b;                 # delete b or block words
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)        # iterate thru all words
        b[$i]=i;              # give each word ad order (* see below)
    for(i=1;i<=(n-1);i++)     # for each word in a see the order of block words
        if(b[a[i]]>b[a[i+1]]) # printing at first mismatch
            print $0
}' test
```

**(*)** I didn't test what happens if a wanted word exist twice in the word block. The last position remains for that word so go figure...

Comment: But how to delete that record from the file? I tried this code, but its not deleting.

Comment: @BBHeeMAA Oh, my bad. It did the opposite. Now fixed.

Comment: How to add a new line between records while printing output?

Comment: You could define `-v ORS="\n\n"`. Oh, the others didn't solve that either.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;N;/^$/M!ba;/I.*am.*a.*happy.*soul/d' file
```

Read multiple lines into the pattern space, on encountering an empty line, match the required string and delete if necessary.

A more bulletproof solution might be:

```
sed ':a;$!{N;/^\s*$/M!ba};/\<I\>.*\<am\>.*\<a\>.*\<happy\>.*\<soul\>/d' file
```